# Jacobian Matrix?

Tags: analysis, matrices, functions, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $f(x,y)=(x^4-y^4,xy)$.

(i) Evaluate the Jacobian of $f$, and its Jacobian determinant.

(ii) Show that $f$ is locally invertible at any point $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

(iii) What is the Jacobian of $f^{-1}$ at the point $(0,1) = f((1,1))$?

(iv) Is $f$ globally invertible on $\mathbb R^2 \backslash(0,0)$?

For part i) Jacobian determinant is $4(x^2+y^2)$.

I'm at loss at part ii, iii and iv. Please help me out...

Lots of thanks!

Comment: Kindly asking if these are you homework? :-)

Comment: No, its nottttt

Comment: @Karen Please review my edit.

Comment: What specifically is giving you trouble?

Comment: I dont understand this topic, that is why I can't answer them

Comment: @ZettaSuro i only know how to get the jacobian det

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on how to approach it? Also, do you know the [inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem)?

Comment: Well i just calculated for part (iii), my inverse function is

Comment: (1/8   1/2)
(-1/8   1/2)
woops, i dont know how to show it here in 2x2 matrix

Answer (score 4):

**HINT** This is the [inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem). It says that if the Jacobian determinant is non-zero at some point $x$, then the function has a *local* inverse: there exists a neighbourhood $U \ni x$ such that $f|U$ is injective, and such that $(f|U)^{-1}$ is continous and differentiable (if $f$ is).

There are lots more details at the Wikipedia page, and a good example too.

For the last question: $f$ cannot be globally invertible, because it is not injective. For any pair $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, we have $f(a,b)=f(-a,-b)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still dont understand for the last question...

Comment: @Karen: It would be helpful if you could clarify which parts you don't understand.

Comment: Why f cannot be globally invertible? What is injective?

Comment: i dont know how to tell that f is not a globally invertible..

Comment: and for part iv, is the inverse is (1/8   1/2)
(-1/8   1/2)? i dont know how to show it here in 2x2 matrix

Answer (score 3):

Put $u=x^4-y^4$ and $v=xy$. Then the Jacobian is the determinant of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
4x^3&-4y^3\\
y&x&\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$
So the Jacobian equals $4(x^4+y^4)$. Hence you have (i). And (ii) follows immediately, since it is clear that the Jacobian is $0$ if and only is $x=0=y$. Also (iv) follows.

According to the inverse function theorem, the matrix inverse of the Jacobian matrix of an invertible function is the Jacobian matrix of the inverse function. So $J(1,1)=8$ and hence of the inverse function $f^{-1}$ it is $\frac{1}{8}$.

Answer (score 0):

@Karen, try to understand what injective means at first as this is a key point for inverse function theorem.

$f(x)$ is injective if $$f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b.$$ For an example, $f(x)=x^2$ is not injective since $f(-1)=f(1)$ does not imply 1=-1. Thus $f(x)=x^2$ is not globally invertible.

Comment: oh i see! now i get what's injective! :)

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Does this apply the same to part (ii)?

Comment: How to tell that f is locally invertible at any point (x,y)=(0,0)?

Comment: Oh I think I know how to tell whether f is locally invertible, when jacobian determinant is not equals to 0.